# C pointers output of following need explanation

Tags: c, pointers

how does the output come out to be JACK?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void *vp;
    char ch = 74, *cp = "JACK";
    int j = 65;
    vp = &ch;
    printf("%c", *(char*)vp);
    vp = &j;
    printf("%c", *(int*)vp);
    vp = cp;
    printf("%s", (char*)vp + 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work on little-endian architecture, so is not a recommended way to print characters.

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling, and failing, to see any value in this to future SO visitors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no use in analysing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
vp = &ch;
printf("%c", *(char*)vp);
```

Output the character with code 74 (J)

```
vp = &j;
printf("%c", *(int*)vp);
```

Output the character with code 65 (A)

```
vp = cp;
printf("%s", (char*)vp + 2);
```

Output the string "JACK" with offset 2 (CK)

=> JACK

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%c", *(char*)vp);` `vp` points to the address of a `char` containing 74 which is ASCII for `'J'`

`printf("%c", *(int*)vp);` `vp` points to the address of an `int` containing 65 which is ASCII for `'A'`

`printf("%s", (char*)vp + 2);` `vp` points to `"Jack"`. When advanced by 2, it prints `"CK"`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
char ch=74
```

74 is the decimal value of the character `'J'` and so, is the same as

```
char ch='J'
```

Here:

```
int j=65;
```

65 is the decimal value of the character `'A'` and so, is the same as

```
int j='A';
```

All these can be seen in [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

So,

```
printf("%c", *(char*)vp);
```

prints `J` as `vp`, at this point, points to the address of `ch` which holds the value 74(`'J'`) and casting it to a `char*` and dereferencing it gives 74(`'J'`).

Similarly,

```
printf("%c", *(int*)vp);
```

prints `A` as `vp`, at this point, points to the address of `j` which holds the value 65(`'A'`) and casting it to an `int*` and dereferencing it gives 65(`'A'`).

Lastly,

```
printf("%s", (char*)vp + 2);
```

is the same as

```
printf("%s", cp + 2);
```

because `vp` points to the address of the first element of `cp`. The above `printf` means "*print everything starting from third character of the string until the NUL-terminator*" and this prints `CK`.